# Set ImageView in a static method

Tags: android, static, imageview

I have a method that needs to be called from another activity, and I need to use it to set an ImageView in it's own activity. I have this method in MainActivity:

```
public static void setImageView(String fileName){
        Log.i(TAG, fileName);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileName);
        imageView.setBackgroundResource(0);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);  
    }
```

But I can't make a static reference to findViewById because it isn't a static method. This method is being called in a Camera Activity after the photo has been saved, I want to pass in the fileName (file URI) and set the imageView such that when the Camera Activity finishes and the user return to the MainActivity the ImageView is already set. As such, in CameraView I am trying to call this:

```
...code...
mCamera.takePicture(null, null, callback);
MainActivity.setImageView(fileName);
```

Is there a cheeky way around this? I know there are other posts on this but I can't quite work out how to apply the advice given there to my situation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should launch your CameraActivity using startActivityForResult() method, and after take the photo put the fileName as an Extra into an Intent and set it as result. Then in your MainActivity you can get the fileName back from the Intent arg of onActivityResult().

Something like:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity{
        public void aMethod(){
            ...
            Intent i = new Intent(this, CameraActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);
            ...
        }
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Bundle b = data.getExtras();
                String fileName = b.getString(RETURN_FILE_PARAMETER);
                doSomething(fileName);
    }
    }
    }

    ...

    public class CameraActivity extends Activity{
        private void returnFileFinishActivity(String fileName) {
            Intent retIntent = new Intent();
            retIntent.putExtra(RETURN_FILE_PARAMETER, fileName);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, retIntent);
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Regards.

Comment: That sounds perfect, and thanks for your code example. I'll read up a little and try to implement it. I'll come back and report when I know if it works!

Comment: I am having a little trouble with RETURN_FILE_PARAMETER, it says it can't resolve it as a variable and suggests declaring it and setting it to null, but doing that doesn't appear to work because I'm not getting fileName back. Thoughts?

Comment: It's a constant with any String value you should use as extra key to set and get the fileName in your Intent

Answer (score 1):

A few things.

1) Since you should only be displaying one activity at a time, why not just start with `startActivityForResult` in the activity with the `ImageView` and override `onActivityResult` in your camera activity?

2) I'm not sure of your application, but it may be easier if you implement taking a picture by following this: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-quick-tip-launching-the-camera/ .

3) You can expose a static reference to your main activity, in your main activity's `onCreate` method, do something like `staticRef = this;` and in your camera activity simply access it via `MainActivity.staticRef...` (I would not recommend this approach)

4) You can register a broadcast receiver in your Main activity that has a reference to your main activity or image view and in your camera activity you send a broadcast to it which you can set the image view

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed reply. startActibityForResult seems like the best approach, it's not something I've used before so I'll make sure I read up a little to fully understand implementing it.

Also, my camera is an OpenCV activity that is highly customised for my specific needs, I've seen variations on your link in point 2 but I always assumed they are limited to using the native camera - is that right?

Comment: Yes, you are limited to using the native camera which is why I asked what your intent was.  For ```startActivityForResult(intent, resultCode)``` and what you'll do when you're done with the image is exactly what eltabo recommends